# SQL Server : get data from another table by joining a table whose ID is active

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to fetch rows of a table suppose table1 by joining another table suppose table2 whose ID are present in one of the two columns of table1 and applying where on table2 with `IsActive =1` which is a column in table2 table but I am not able to fetch the proper data.

Table1 is like below:

```
table1_ID|column_x|column_y
---------+--------+---------
1        |29      |30
2        |30      |31
3        |31      |32
```

table2 is like:

```
table2_ID|IsActive
---------+--------
29       |1
30       |1
31       |1
32       |0
```

Now below is my query:

```
SELECT 
    table2.[table2_id],
    table2.[column_x],
    table2.[[column_y]
FROM 
    [table2] 
WHERE 
    (table2.[column_x] IN (SELECT table1_id FROM table1 WHERE IsActive = 1)
    OR table2.[[column_y] IN (SELECT table1_id FROM table1 WHERE IsActive = 1))
```

But I get all the rows but I am expecting something like:

```
table1_ID|column_x|column_y
---------+--------+---------
1        |29      |30
2        |30      |31
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your need well, both of this SQL statements should do the work:

```
SELECT 
    table1.table1_id,
    table1.column_x,
    table1.column_y
FROM table1
WHERE table1.column_x IN (SELECT table2_id FROM table2 WHERE IsActive = 1) AND
      table1.column_y IN (SELECT table2_id FROM table2 WHERE IsActive = 1)
```

```
SELECT 
    table1.table1_id,
    table1.column_x,
    table1.column_y
FROM table1
JOIN table2 X ON X.table2_id = table1.column_x
JOIN table2 Y ON Y.table2_id = table1.column_y
WHERE X.IsActive = 1 AND
      Y.IsActive = 1
```